# Riemann integral property

Tags: calculus

In my calculus textboox appears the following statement about the Riemann integral:

Let R([a,b]) be the set of all Riemann integrable functions of [a,b].

i) If [c,d] ⊂ [a,b] and f ∈ R([a,b]), then f ∈ R([c,d]).

I am trying to see why f ∈ R([c,d]), but I can't seem to understand why should f belong to a subinterval of [a,b].

Comment: $f$ doesn't *belong* to a subinterval. You're just looking at the part of the graph of $f$ over the interval $[c,d]$. So if you have area under the curve on $[a,b]$, why do you have area under the curve under the subinterval $[c,d]$?  [If you're trying to prove it, consider partitions of $[a,b]$ that use points $c$ and $d$.]

Comment: See my answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236665/help-proving-elementray-properties-of-the-riemann-integral-using-only-the-rieman/2247755#2247755) .